# "Longest Palindromic Substring" challenge solution is inefficient

Tags: java, algorithm, strings, programming-challenge, palindrome

I am trying to solve the [Longest Palindromic Substring problem](http://leetcode.com/onlinejudge#question_5) on LeetCode, and I have come up with a DP solution pasted below:

```
public class Solution {
    String      string;
    boolean[][] visited;
    String[][]  results;

    private boolean isPalindrome(String s){
        String test = new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString();
        if(test.equals(s)) return true; else return false;
    }

    private String maxLengthString(String... args){
        String result = new String();
        for(String arg:args){
            if(arg.length() > result.length()) result = arg;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private String findLongestPalindrome(int start,int end){
        if(start >= end) return new String();
        else if(start >= string.length() || start < 0) return new String();
        else if(end <= 0 || end > string.length()) return new String();
        else{
            if(visited[start][end-1] == true) return results[start][end-1];
            String result = new String();
            if(this.isPalindrome(string.substring(start,end)))
                result = maxLengthString(string.substring(start,end),
                                        findLongestPalindrome(start+1,end),
                                        findLongestPalindrome(start,end-1));
            else result = maxLengthString(findLongestPalindrome(start+1,end),
                                          findLongestPalindrome(start,end-1));
            visited[start][end-1] = true;
            results[start][end-1] = result;
            return result;
        }
    }

    public String longestPalindrome(String s) {
        // Start typing your Java solution below
        // DO NOT write main() function

        string = s;
        visited = new boolean[s.length()][s.length()];
        results = new String[s.length()][s.length()];

        return findLongestPalindrome(0,s.length());
    }
}
```

The algorithm is quite straightforward, but the online judge complains about it not being efficient enough. I am just wondering if this algorithm is slow by nature (in which case I have to find another algorithm) or if it's something about my implementation.

Comment: Also, it's probably slow because of the recursion.

Comment: I see you are using a recursive approach. Have you tried to create an iterative solution and compare the results?

Comment: @bblincoe I will try later

Comment: @Bohemian I'd imagine, to become efficient enough, it would require a fundamentally different approach, i.e. basically a complete rewrite. Wouldn't this be beyond the scope of [codereview.se]? UPDATE - Well, the question doesn't actually seem to be asking about a different approach, just why it's slow, so it may be fine for there, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3):

### Why is it slow?

The input string `S` can be up to 1000 characters.

Your DP solution considers all \$\mathcal{O}(|S|^2)\$ substrings of `S` and you're checking for each of these substrings, if it is a palindrome, in linear time in terms of the length of this substring.

### Faster solutions

You can do it easily in \$\mathcal{O}(|S|^2)\$ using a polynomial hashing technique.

There are of course more sophisticated and linear solutions based on the famous [Manacher algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_palindromic_substring).

Answer (score 3):

The proper way to solve it is to use a profiler to determine where the bottlenecks are, but by inspection, your search tree is at least twice the size it has to be *and* you will always expand the entire tree rather than terminating when you can.

```
if(this.isPalindrome(string.substring(start,end)))
            result = maxLengthString(string.substring(start,end),
                                    findLongestPalindrome(start+1,end),
                                    findLongestPalindrome(start,end-1));
        else result = maxLengthString(findLongestPalindrome(start+1,end),
                                      findLongestPalindrome(start,end-1));
```

if this.isPalindrome is true, then there is no way that findLongestPalindrome(start+1,end) or (start,end-1) could be longer. Rewriting this gives:

```
if(this.isPalindrome(sting.substring(start,end)))
    result = string.substring(start,end)
else
    ...
```

Comment: In the worst case it doesn't help at all